# android firebase изменение пароля

Tags: android, firebase

```
public void updatePassword() {
    // [START update_password]
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String newPassword = password.getText().toString();
user.updatePassword(newPassword)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User password updated.");
                    }
                }
            });
    // [END update_password]
}
```

изменяю пароль, все работает и при входе требует новый пароль.
Но в самой базе нет изменения, пароль старый почему так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Пароли пользователей в Realtime базе данных нельзя хранить, они хранятся на серверах Firebase в зашифрованном виде или в виде хешей и ты к ним не имеешь доступ.
Но если все же решишь хранить их в Realtime, то просто добавь следующий код:

```
String UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference firebaseDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
firebaseDb.child("Users").child(UID).child("password").setValue(password);
```